# How can I redirect to a function that is further down in my code?

Tags: linux, bash, function, shell

```
if [[ $adapter == "1" ]]; then

LINE 66 > usepreferredadapter

elif [[ $adapter == "2" ]]; then

echo -e "\e[0mI'm sorry you do not own the requirements to proceed!"
echo "Try using the adapter that's build in , into your computer (not working on Virtualbox or VMware)"
echo -e "\e[31mNote that build in adapters are over all bad for hacking!\e[0m"
echo "Script will exit!"
exit



else

echo "Invalid input!"
echo "Script will exit!"
exit


fi

LINE 89 > function usepreferredadapter(){
```

In line 66, I want the user to be redirected to the function in line 89, how can I do that (if it's even possible)?

Comment: Are you trying to use the function before defining it? If so, that won't work in shell. A function definition is an *executable command*, and has no effect *until it's executed*.

Comment: You write "redirect", do you mean "call"? Also, on line 66, could you put anything that isn't part of your real code to the end of the line behind a `#` character, so your code is valid? I'm assuming `LINE 66 >` is merely a comment, but as is, it'd cause an error.

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stacked. What did you try?

Answer (score 1):

In order to avoid this kind of behaviour I suggest you to put all your code in a main function, so that everything is loaded when you need it

E.G.

```
#!/bin/bash
main() {
  if [[ $adapter == "1" ]]; then
    usepreferredadapter
  elif [[ $adapter == "2" ]]; then
    ...
  fi
}

function usepreferredadapter(){
  ...
}

main "$@"
```

This way, it doesn't matter where you define your method as long you call the main method at the bottom of your script

Answer (score 0):

Try shifting the function definition before the line where the function is called, i.e. shift your function definition at line #89 to some place before line #66.